# Multiple XML Query Issues

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

For a project that I am working on I need to query one XML URL and retrieve a list of players using a predetermined franchise id. With those player ids I need to query a second XML URL and retrieve the player names and teams, then display it in a list.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**First Query**

URL: http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/2007/export?TYPE=rosters&L=46184

- I need to select each player id that is listed under a predetermined franchise id.

**Second Query**

URL: http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=players&PLAYERS=3291

- Here I need to be able to retrieve the player name and team using the player id we retrieved from the specific franchise id, in the first query.

After all of this I would like to have the results of the second query show up in a list.

This means that from the first query something like 15 player ids could be retrieved and with those player ids I need to figure out a way to get each individual player name and team.

Would anyone be willing to help me out here? I can provide more information if you ask.

```
// Parse and display
$data=array();

$url1 = "http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/2007/export?TYPE=rosters&L=46184";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url1);
 foreach($xml->franchise->player as $franchise_one) {
  $id=(string) $franchise_one->attributes()->id;
  $data[$id]['id']=(string) $franchise_one->attributes()->id;
  $data[$id]['playerid']=(string) $franchise_one->attributes()->id;
 }

/* Query list to get player names and teams using the player ids from above */
$url2 = "http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=players&PLAYERS=3291";
$xml_second = simplexml_load_file($url2);
 foreach($xml_second->players->player as $player) {
  $id=(string) $player->attributes()->id;
   $data[$id]['name']=(string) $player->attributes()->name;
 }

while(list($key,$franchise)=each($data)) {
 $list .= 'Franchise id: '.$franchise['id'].'<br/>Player id: '.$franchise['playerid'].'<br/>Player name: '.$player['name'].'<br/><br/>';
}
```

**Results**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in --- on line 41

Franchise id: 8025
Player id: 8025
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 7394
Player id: 7394
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 6780
Player id: 6780
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 7740
Player id: 7740
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 5004
Player id: 5004
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 5656
Player id: 5656
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 4914
Player id: 4914
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 6562
Player id: 6562
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 7403
Player id: 7403
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 7393
Player id: 7393
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 8266
Player id: 8266
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 6528
Player id: 6528
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 7653
Player id: 7653
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 6952
Player id: 6952
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 8339
Player id: 8339
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 8074
Player id: 8074
 Player name: l

Franchise id: 0521
Player id: 0521
 Player name: l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
$year         = '2007';
$league       = '46184';
$franchise_id = '0001';

// Parse and display
$data=array();

// Get players for each franchise
$url = 'http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/'.$year.'/export?TYPE=rosters&L='.$league.'&FRANCHISE='.$franchise_id.'';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
 foreach($xml->franchise->player as $franchise_two) {
  $player_id=(string) $franchise_two->attributes()->id;
   $data[$player_id]['playerid']=(string) $franchise_two->attributes()->id;

    // Create a list of player ids
    $player_list = ''.$data[$player_id]['playerid'].',';

     // Parse players
     $players = simplexml_load_file('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=players&PLAYERS='.$player_list.'');
      foreach ($players as $player):
       $player_name=$player['name'];
      endforeach;

       // Display output
       while(list($key,$franchise)=each($data)) {
        $list .= 'Franchise id: '.$franchise_id.'<br/>Player id: '.$franchise['playerid'].'<br/>Player name: '.$player_name.'<br/><br/>';
       }
}

echo ''.$list.'';
```

**Echo result**

Franchise id: 0001

Player id: 8025

Player name: Anderson, Derek

Etc...